# AWS: Problem accessing metadata tags from within EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, metadata

```
curl -v http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
*   Trying 169.254.169.254:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 169.254.169.254 port 80 failed: Timed out
* Failed to connect to 169.254.169.254 port 80: Timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 169.254.169.254 port 80: Timed out
```

O.S : Windows 10.

Access to all other websites work but not this IP that has metadata about the instance.

Comment: Can you try turning off the Windows Firewall to see if this helps?

Comment: Windows 10? Are you talking about Amazon WorkSpaces rather than EC2?

Comment: 169 is private ip range, I hope you are calling it within ec2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue recently. In my case, there was no route to `169.254.169.254` present in my route table.

Therefore I would first do a `route print` from the command line and confirm whether or not any routes present to the destination `169.254.169.254`.

In my case, the solution was to simply restart the `Ec2Config` windows service to get the route added.

Hope this helps.

Reference:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/waiting-for-metadata/